# Tree from OpenCL to c++

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, opencl

I need to process a tree in OpenCL. Problem is: I need to load the tree to OpenCL and it consists of many pointers. I dont want to put all the nodes into and array, but is there any other solution?

Comment: if you dont want to use an array use a vector instead ?

Comment: This is poorly worded. I'm not sure what you're asking. What type of tree, what does "load the tree to OpenCL" mean? Why do you not want to use an array (or any other container?)?